# How can I add raw values for an enum that doesn't have it?

Tags: swift, enums

Given an external enum that I can't change:

```
enum MyEnum {
  case first
  case second
}
```

How would I best make this RawRepresentable, or at least convertible to an Int (or String) ?

I could write an extension to mimic rawValue, but this feels rather clumsy:

```
extension MyEnum {

    enum EnumError: Error {
        case invalidValue
    }

    init (rawValue: Int) throws {
        switch rawValue {
        case 0:
            self = .first
        case 1:
            self = .second
        default:
            throw EnumError.invalidValue
        }
    }

    var rawValue: Int {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return 0
        case .second:
            return 1
        }
    }
}
```

What is a better way?

Comment: Can you tell what are you trying to do with this enum? It may be [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Store the value in NSUserDefaults. If you owned this you could just type it as Int or add raw/associated values to it. 

Maybe this is XY as you say. Can I just store the enum and read it as AnyObject and cast ?

Comment: This article might not be a your question's answer

but i recommend this article use enum more advanced way with many example check it out https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/ @FelixSFD thank for your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case first
    case second
}

extension MyEnum {
    enum MyExtendedEnum:Int {
        case first
        case second
    }
}
```

Its a bit more cleaner code anyways, and your call is now:

```
let myVar = MyEnum.MyExtendedEnum.RawValue()
```